# java fetch environment variable ending with specific string

Tags: java

I need to fetch 2 environment variables from the system variables that end with a particular string. The strings are PORT & HOST.
For example I have the following variables:

```
TEST_SERVICE1_PORT = 80
TEST_SERVICE1_HOST = 0.0.0.0
TEST_SERVICE2_PORT = 78
TEST_SERVICE2_HOST = 1.1.1.1
TEST_SERVICE3_PORT = 90
TEST_SERVICE3_HOST = 2.2.2.2
TEST_SERVICE4_PORT = 100
TEST_SERVICE4_HOST = 3.3.3.3
```

Plus other system variables

Here's what I'm able to do:

```
var map = System.getenv().entrySet().stream()
                            .filter(x -> x.getKey().endsWith(serviceName + "_PORT"  ) || x.getKey().endsWith(serviceName + "_HOST"))
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getKey(), x -> x.getValue()));
// serviceName is a custom input
```

For example if servicename is SERVICE1, the map would have the first 2 variables.

From this map, I need to fetch the PORT & HOST value.

How can I do that? Do I have to again filter the resultant map or is there a better way?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Could you please add the output of `System.out.println(System.getenv());` I have the feeling that these env variables are not made available to your application

Comment: These are dummy values but I have verified that the resultant map contains these values if I add it manually.

Comment: A concatenated string would be the ideal solution. Storing in a list would mean again filtering is needed to make out which is the host & port variable since the sequence of variables can be different.

Comment: _For example if servicename is SERVICE1, the map would have the first 2 variables._ You have a `Map` with two entries. The value in one entry is the port, for example `80`. The value in the other entry is an IP address, for example `0.0.0.0`. I don't understand what you want to do with these two values. What do you mean by: _From this map, I need to fetch the PORT & HOST value_ Can't you just write `String port = map.get("TEST_SERVICE1_PORT")` ?

Comment: the thing is TEST can be any string so I can't hardcode that part. SERVICE1_PORT is the string that I'm certain. That's why I can't do a simple get.

Comment: How can you use the `var` keyword when you are using `[java-8]`?

Comment: Can you rely on the assumption that there are only two entries passing the filter? Then, you can use something like `System.getenv().entrySet().stream() .filter(x -> { String k = x.getKey(); return (k.endsWith("_PORT"  ) || k.endsWith("_HOST")) && k.regionMatches(k.length() - serviceName.length() - 5, serviceName, 0, serviceName.length()); }) .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getKey().substring(x.getKey().length() - 4), Map.Entry::getValue))` which will always produce a map with the keys `"PORT"` and `"HOST"`.

Comment: It should be 2 but I can't be definite about that.

Comment: @Holger can you shed some light on your code please.

Comment: The crucial part is using `x -> x.getKey().substring(x.getKey().length() - 4)` as key function for `toMap`, to use only the last four characters. Of course, when you can’t rely on a unique prefix, there’s no way around another operation to identify the existing prefix. Besides that, I just rewrote the filter to avoid performing string concatenations for every entry test.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it.